# Joining 2 Tables (Having 3 common columns) on the basis of only two common columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Tables - Employee and Job_History 
and
Both the tables have 3 common columns in it - EMPLOYEE_ID, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID.

Now, **I want to Join both the tables using JOIN** but not on the basis of all 3 common columns **BUT on the basis of only 2 common columns - EMPLOYEE_ID and JOB_ID**.

How can i get the result ?

Comment: what you tried so far . show your query

Comment: Joined two tables on the basis of 1 column :<br/> SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN JOB_HISTORY USING (EMPLOYEE_ID); <br/>  Joined two tables on the basis of all 3 column : <br/> SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEES NATURAL JOIN JOB_HISTORY; <br/> But i don't know which JOIN should i used so that i can get the desired output.

Comment: you need to use On clause . see my below answer

Comment: @Sagar Arora That was rather quick to accept, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `multiple` condition in  `JOIN` `on` clause   like this

```
select E.* ,J.* 
from Employee as E 
   inner join Job_History as J 
   on (E.EMPLOYEE_ID=J.EMPLOYEE_ID 
        and E.JOB_ID=J.JOB_ID)
```

Comment: This is a valid method, but he does not *need* to use the `ON` clause.

Comment: @McGlothlin . . . This is the correct way to write the query.  I don't know what your comment refers to, but putting the `JOIN` conditions in the `ON` clause is correct.

Comment: Oh, in a comment on OP's question, he said the `ON` clause was needed. I took that to mean *required*. I'm merely saying there's another way to do it.

Comment: It was a pedantic comment for sure. There's certainly nothing wrong with doing it this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` on as many or as few columns as you'd like. The `JOIN` conditions tells the database how to merge the data from the tables.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES
JOIN JOB_HISTORY USING (EMPLOYEE_ID, JOB_ID)
```

If the values in `DEPARTMENT_ID` also match up in both tables where `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `JOB_ID` are equivalent, the result set will be the same regardless of whether or not you also include `DEPARTMENT_ID`.

If I have the following columns in each table:

```
Table A
EMPLOYEE_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  JOB_ID  Other_Column1  Other_Column2
1            1              1       stuff          things
2            2              2       stuff          things
3            3              3       stuff          things

Table B
EMPLOYEE_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  JOB_ID  Other_Column3  Other_Column4
1            1              1       stuff          things
2            2              2       stuff          things
3            3              3       stuff          things
```

then the joins would be equivalent whether you include `DEPARTMENT_ID` or not. However if `DEPARTMENT_ID` were `1, 2, 3` in table A and `2, 3, 4` in table B:

```
Table A
EMPLOYEE_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  JOB_ID  Other_Column1  Other_Column2
1            1              1       stuff          things
2            2              2       stuff          things
3            3              3       stuff          things

Table B
EMPLOYEE_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  JOB_ID  Other_Column3  Other_Column4
1            2              1       stuff          things
2            3              2       stuff          things
3            4              3       stuff          things
```

the result set would return no results because there are no cases where the three columns, `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `DEPARTMENT_ID`, and `JOB_ID` all match for a given row.